# Visual Graph Traversal in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, maps, directed-graph

I'm working on a homework assignment, in which I have to traverse a map of Paris (png format) to navigate between 15 different landmarks.  I need to be able to start navigation from any point on the map, and reach the landmarks in a user defined order.

My approach to this project is to overlay a directed graph over the roads on the map, associating nodes with road intersections and landmarks.  This is where I have a question.  Is there a control where I can draw a graph in my window, or will I need to set each node and edges in the code, and associate each node with a point?

Comment: Don't know much about WPF but I just wanted to say that where I live is actually evening. Good luck though.

Comment: There is an article on codeproject discussing graph-visualization. You might want to take a look at it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43776/Using-WPF-to-Visualize-a-Graph-with-Circular-Depen